# Different way to solve Hartshorne Question 1.4.7

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Firstly I am aware that this has been answered before, but the answers there used different methods to answer this question. I would like to understand the specific solution given here.

http://math.uchicago.edu/~drewmoore/researchnotes/Hartshorne1_4.pdf

(at the top of page three)

Here is the question, vertabim, from Hartshorne.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two varieties. Suppose there are points $P\in X$ and $Q\in Y$ such that the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{P,X}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Q,Y}$ are isomorphic as $k$-algebras. Then show that there are open sets $P\in U\subset X$ and $Q\in V\subset Y$ and an isomorphism of $U$ to $V$ which sends $P$ to $Q$.

I am completely cool with assuming $X$ and $Y$ are affine and translation. That is all good. I also understand that $\mathcal{O}_{P,X}\cong \mathcal{O}_{Q,Y}$ implies that $A(X)_{m_{0}}\cong A(Y)_{m_0'}$. Note here, unlike the document I am letting $m_{0}=\{f\in A(X)|f(0)\neq 0\}$ and $m_{0}'=\{g\in A(Y)|g(0)\neq 0\}$ in order to avoid confusion. Now this is where I begin to get confused

> This induces an ismorphism of $K(X)$ with $K(Y)$.

I don't see how this comes about, I have checked Hartshorne extensively, especially theorems 3.2, 4.4 and corollary 4.5. Maybe one of these theorems does imply this, but I am not seeing this.

Anyway, assuming the above is true then I have that from corollary 4.5 in Hartshorne that $X$ and $Y$ are birationally equivalent. And thus there will exist open $U\in X$ and $V\in Y$ such that $U$ is isomorphic to $V$. However at this stage we don't know if $P$ is in $U$ or if $Q$ is in $V$.

The rest of the solution is quite confusing. In particular the line

> Further, we know that this map is given by the images $\frac{f_i}{g_i}$ of $x_i$ in $K(Y)$

What is/are the $x_i$, are they co-ordinates of some point, or are they indeterminates. Are the $f_i/g_i$ in $K(Y)$ or...Anyway, hopefully my confusion is made clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fraction fields of $A(X)_{m_0}$ and $A(Y)_{m_0'}$ are $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ respectively. Just go through the proof of Theorem 4.4 in Hartshorne, you'll see what is happening.

Comment: The link you posted is no longer there : (( But I think the map you're referring to could be $A_{\mathfrak{m}_P}$ as defined by Hartshorne? Particularly, we can define the localization $A(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_{P}}$ as
    $$ A(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_{P}}=\left\{\frac{f+I(X)}{g+I(X)}: \begin{array}{c}f+I(X) \in A(X), g+I(X) \notin \mathfrak{m}_{P} \\ 1 \end{array}\right\} $$. Then it follows that the quotient field of $A(X)$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $\mathcal{O}_{P.X}$ for every $P$, which is equal to $K(X)$.

Comment: Also for the second part, binationality implies that the rational functions are dense, so $P \in U$, $Q \in V$.